# App icons are missing for certain flatpak apps in the plank

Tags: plank, icons, release-odin

With Notes-Up when I click on the new note icon is missing and Blue recorder I found that icon is missing too in plank.
[image: Notes-Up]

[image: Blue recorder]

Comment: I am having this same problem today, with the apps Tuner, and Ordne. No icon but the placeholder gear for either.  Fully up to date, new install